# Transition to a new ViewController embedded in an UINavigationController causes animation problem

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I use a rootViewController and I want to move to another ViewController. The transition to the newViewController works with that code.

A problem occurs when the newViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController. Then the navigation bar is animating during the animation and changes the position.

The navigation bar is animating from the top left to the correct position.

```
fileprivate func animateTransition(to newViewController: UIViewController) {
    currentViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    addChild(newViewController)
    newViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    transition(from: currentViewController, to: newViewController, duration: 2, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.currentViewController.removeFromParent()
        newViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.currentViewController = newViewController
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

How is it possible to move to another UINavigationController with a "fade" animation and how can the navigation bar be at the correct position right from the beginning of the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should move your view controller clean-up code call from the `animations` closure into the `completion` closure:

```
currentViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
addChild(newViewController)
newViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
transition(from: currentViewController, to: newViewController, duration: 2, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
    // this is intentionally blank
}, completion: { _ in
    self.currentViewController.removeFromParent()
    newViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    self.currentViewController = newViewController
})
```

You don't want to indicate the transition is done until the animation is complete.

To the navigation bar issue, rather than letting `transition(from:to:duration:...)` handle the manipulation of the view controller hierarchy, you can add it to your view hierarchy and then animate the unhiding of it. Usually you'd use the `.showHideTransitionViews` option, but `transition` is still doing something curious with the appearance methods that is confusing the navigation controller, so it's best to just animate it yourself:

```
currentViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
addChild(newViewController)
newViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
newViewController.view.alpha = 0
view.addSubview(newViewController.view)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    newViewController.view.alpha = 1
}, completion: { _ in
    self.currentViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.currentViewController.removeFromParent()
    newViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    self.currentViewController = newViewController
})
```

That will allow it to present the navigation bar correctly from the beginning and just fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this underneath the class declaration of the newViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

if you already have a viewDidLoad() in your ViewController, then just use the last part.

If that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: I tried to add that in the custom UINavigationController class as well as in the newViewController. Unfortunately, that does not work.